# Bundle error on creation of a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having problems to create a **Ruby on Rails** project on my Mac. It takes a long time for the command bundle install to finish when I use the command `rails new project`. After that, the following error appears:

> NoMethodError: private method `open' called for Gem::Package:Class An
>   error occured while installing rake (10.0.3), and Bundler cannot
>   continue. Make sure that`gem install rake -v '10.0.3'` succeeds
>   before bundling.

I already got rake 10.0.3 installed. I've checked using `gem list`. Any ideas about this error ?

Comment: I have no idea what might be happening but try update bundler

Comment: Which version of Ruby (`ruby -v`)? Which version of RubyGems (`gem -v`)?

Comment: gem is 2.0.0 and ruby ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.0].

Comment: Ta for the quick response. What's your Bundler version? `bundle -v`

Comment: Bundler version 1.1.5

Comment: I'm only having this problem with ruby 1.9.3. If I switch to 1.8.7 it works perfectly. But I want to start coding with 1.9.3, because 1.8.7 will no longer be supported on Rails 4.

Comment: Install rake as the error told you to do and paste the results here... gem install rake -v '10.0.3'

Comment: Which version of Rails (`rails -v`) are you using? Do all the gems in discussion show up when you run `gem list`?

Comment: @ScottS., it installs normally. But when I try to create a project the error persists.

Comment: Yes @ChristophPetschnig.

Comment: Have you compared the version number (or location of) the `gem` command with `bundle exec gem` to see if there is a difference?

Comment: @ScottS. , I've solved the problem. I removed my RVM, deleted the folder in usr/local/rvm. Uninstalled Mac Ports. Installed rvm and ruby again. Although I don't know how it helped..

Comment: i am also have this issue. gem 2.0,ruby 1.9.3-p194, bundle -1.2.0.

Comment: @ajahongir. Do you use Mac OS X?

Comment: thanks guys for support.
@andrefurquin, i have solved my problem by reinstalling ruby at rvm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Ran 'gem update' from inside my Rails site directory, it updated bundler along with a few other gems, then ran 'bundle install' and it worked.

Hope this helps!